# Get the lowest date for each row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an sql query which returns result in this way:

```
id  first_date                          second_date                         third_date
1   12-AUG-13 04.41.42.658000000 PM     07-JUL-14 10.24.02.188000000 AM     06-JAN-12 11.20.01.148000000 AM
2   11-AUG-12 04.41.42.658000000 PM     06-SEP-13 09.22.02.188000000 AM     04-FEB-12 11.20.01.148000000 AM
```

How can I get the lowest date for each row so result can be presented in this way?

```
id  lowest_date_for_each_row
1   06-JAN-12 11.20.01.148000000 AM
2   04-FEB-12 11.20.01.148000000 AM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`least`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm) function:

```
select id, least(first_date, second_date, thrid_date)
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the LEAST function should do what you ant:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/least.php

So something like

```
SELECT id, LEAST(first_date, second_date, third_date) leastDate FROM datesTable
```